# How to study the sign of an expression including a function, with conditions on the function?

Tags: functions, differential-equations, assumptions

I'm trying to study the sign of an expression, having information on some of my parameters. I don't know how to code these conditions. For example, I want to know when this expression:

```
k (2(a'[x])^2 - a[x]a''[x]) / (a[x]^2)
```

is positive given that `k > 0`, `x > 0` and that my function `a` is positive and increasing for all `x > 0` (`k` is a constant, `a` is a function)

So basically, since `a''[x]` is the only term of the equation that I don't know anything about, I want *Mathematica* to give me:

```
(* a''[x] < a'[x]^2/a[x] *)
```

Comment: Elsa, welcome to Mathematica.SE.  Please use backticks to format your code so that your question is more readable; see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @Elsa I did not clearly understand, what is your aim. Think about adding an example of a function in question along with the answer in the form you wish it to be. You can do it using the option "edit" below your question.

Comment: Hello Elsa, my apologies that your edit went unnoticed and you had to wait so long... I've formatted the question a bit and reopened it :) I've also changed `"` to `''` since `"` is used only for strings and it looks like you meant the second derivative. Please also clarify if `k` here is a function or just a quantity. Your usage of `[]`, when interpreted as _Mathematica_ syntax indicates that `k` is a function, but if interpreted purely as a grouping, then perhaps not.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your edit! (indeed, I meant the 2nd derivative and k is just a quantity). Cheers

Comment: Ok this is good enough actually, thank you. Is there any way I wouldn't have to repeat `k>0` in every function but settle it beforehand? (I tried different things on the same idea as `testParam = {k -> 3}`but it doesn't work with inequalities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions need to be answered, so I guess I will shoot:

```
Reduce[k (2 (a'[x])^2 - a[x] a''[x])/(a[x]^2) > 0 && k > 0]
```

> $a'(x)\in \mathbb{R}\land \left(\left(a(x)<0\land a''(x)>\frac{2
>    a'(x)^2}{a(x)}\land k>0\right)\lor \left(a(x)>0\land a''(x)<\frac{2
>    a'(x)^2}{a(x)}\land k>0\right)\right)$

which is the result that you expected.

---

Regarding your [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47156/how-to-study-the-sign-of-an-expression-including-a-function-with-conditions-on#comment144011_47156):

> Is there any way I wouldn't have to repeat k>0 in every function but settle it beforehand?

You can do:

```
assum = k > 0;
Reduce[k (2 (a'[x])^2 - a[x] a''[x])/(a[x]^2) > 0 && assum]
```

Comment: That's awesome! thank you